# vectorization of Segmentation map to RGB colors

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, semantic-segmentation

I have written a function that returns an RGB color map of a segmentation mapped input. The problem is I have used "for" loops for the operation and it's really slow. The function is below:

```
def segment_map_to_rgb_color_image(color_group, segment_map):
    
         rgb_color_image = np.zeros((len(segment_map[0]), len(segment_map[1]), 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    
         for i in range(np.size(segment_map, axis=0)):
             for j in range(np.size(segment_map, axis=1)):
                 idx = segment_map[i][j]
                 for p in range(len(color_group[0])):  
                     rgb_color_image[i][j][p] = color_group[idx][p]                    
                    
         return rgb_color_image
```

Details:

`color_group` is `[256, 3]` NumPy array, where each index corresponds to a specific RGB color, for example, `color_group[0] = [184, 212, 52]`.

`segment_map` is `[height, width]` NumPy array, where each pixel is an integer between 0 and 255.

`rgb_color_image` is `[height, width, 3]` NumPy array.

I am having a difficulty in vectorizing the function and the current non-vectorized function is too slow for real-time analysis.

Can someone help me vectorize the function? All inputs appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy one for `numpy`:

```py
rgb_color_image = color_group[segment_map]
```

This simply uses [fancy indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing).